# I have a problem with the input() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, input

**I'm new to Python and Visual Studio Code.**

Recently I tried to run the following code in VS Code for practice purposes.

```
even_or_not_number = input("Enter a number: ")
even_or_not_number = int(even_or_not_number)
even_test = even_or_not_number % 2
print(even_test == 0)
```

The problem comes when I can't interact with the input() function that I put in my code. In the terminal it appears as if the 2 lines were merged and therefore the code doesn't work.

```
>>> even_or_not_number = input("Enter a number: ")
Enter a number: even_or_not_number = int(even_or_not_number)
>>> even_check = even_or_not_number % 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
>>> print(even_check == 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'even_check' is not defined
```

I understand it's a problem with the VS Code because the code works as expected in the Python IDLE.
What could I have moved in VS Code to make this happen?

Comment: You are apparently trying to run your code by pasting it into a Python interactive prompt - that's not going to work with `input()`, because the next line of pasted text will get used as the input, rather than actually executed.  You need to save your code as a file, then run that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension, then execute the script file with `Run Python File`.

[image]

*https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial*

If you want to use the python interactive, refer to [this document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py#_using-the-python-interactive-window).

You can also select the code in the `.py` file and use the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open an interactive terminal and execute the selected part of the code.